# Forgot password function is loading forever while sending an email to user,why?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to implement forgot password function on a web application. The problem is next: user enters the email, the token is created in the database, so basically this function works, but the application is loading non-stop and the email is not being sent. Also no errors are being displayed.
My mail settings allow this type of interaction.

This is my YML file

```
version: 2
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          facebook:
            client-id: 2275939509018
            client-secret: edd8229d33942a2ef361c8f40afcfa2f
            scope:
              - email
              - public_profile
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_registration
    username: root
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        format_sql: true
        show_sql: true

  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    password: password
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    port: 465
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
    username: email(replaced for stackoverflow)
```

This is my controller class

```
package com.example.mysql;


import com.example.mysql.exception.UserNotFoundException;
import com.example.mysql.model.user.User;
import com.example.mysql.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.mysql.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import net.bytebuddy.utility.RandomString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class ForgotPasswordController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

@Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping("/forgot_password")
    public String showForgotPasswordForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Forgot Password");

        return "forgot_password_form";
    }
    @PostMapping("/forgot_password")
    public String processForgotPasswordForm(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            Model model){
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
       String token =  RandomString.make(30);


        try {
           userService.updateResetPasswordToken(token, email);

            String resetPasswordLink = Utility.getSiteURL(request) + "/reset_password?token"  + token;

          sendEmail(email, resetPasswordLink);


        } catch (UserNotFoundException ex) {
          model.addAttribute("error", ex.getMessage());
      } catch
        (UnsupportedEncodingException | MessagingException e) {
           model.addAttribute("error", "Error while sending email.");
        }

        return "forgot_password_form";
    }

    private void sendEmail(String email, String resetPasswordLink) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setFrom("bob.in.wonderland.library@gmail.com", "Library Support");
        helper.setTo(email);

        String subject = "Here's the link to reset your password";

        String content = "<p> Hello, </p>"
                + "<p>You have requested to reset your password.</p>"
                + "<p>Click the link below to change your password: </p>"
                + "<p><b><a href=\"" + resetPasswordLink + "\"> Change my password </a><b></p>"
                + "<p>Ignore this email if you do remember your password, or you have not made the request </p>";
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setText(content, true);

        mailSender.send(message);

    }
}
```

[User enters the email here, token is being created in database, but loading never ends and email is not being sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp1et.png)

[My mail settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCe7m.png)

Comment: Take a thread dump of your application with `jstack` and see what state it's in.

Comment: Unlikely to be a direct cause of the problem you currently have, but the URL you make is missing an `=` symbol in between `"?token"` and the actual token.